Is it possible in Windows (in service or driver) to receive message (signal) just before OS shuts down
I have SBC which runs an app under Windows 10. It is a part of an embedded system. The SBC is powered via our board (it has its own MCU). When the system shuts down I need to know when I can safely cut the power.
Does Windows send messages to the services/drivers just before shutting down? I would to send information to my board informing that it is safe to cut the power to the board.

In Services,If I remember, all Services have many actions like when Windows Start\Service Start... try to subscribe to one of them

Have a look https://superuser.com/q/773651/1799981

@MustafaMutasim it is far too early. I need to know just before windows physically shuts (not start shutdown)

Ah ok, you are looking for the last second before power cutting off from motherboard, I'm afraid there is no way. Since you are an expert in c what about programming a sensor for that !

At the driver level there is IoRegisterShutdownNotification(), IoRegisterLastChanceShutdownNotification(), and IRP_MJ_POWER/IRP_MN_SET_POWER.
